# Finding duplicates

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

People often ask me*, "Kuba how come you can so quickly find duplicates? It appears tough in this syntax rich environment."

If a question feels like a duplicate or a one that is already answered, it probably is. Here is how you can speed up searching for a duplicate:**

- [Efficient querying with SE search engine and other general rules](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2403/5478)
- [Index of 'There is a function exactly for that' answers](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2404/5478)
- [Index of *characteristic syntax* lookup](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2405/5478)

(*) no they don't but they should! :)

(**) feel free to contribute to that topic

Comment: (+1) Totally helpful - you can take the rest of the week off now! :)

Comment: @gwr Thanks :) I am not done with all bookmarks, not a very interesting task so I will do this gradually.

Answer (score 17):

Very often the answer is obvious but good luck finding `list[[##]]& @@ {1,2,5}` or `Table[With[{i = i}, ...`. I keep that list of bookmarks as well.

This list is slightly subjective because the piece of code is what I think characterizes the answer or the problem best. In case of answers it does not need to be the best answer but probably the most idiomatic one in WL.

Once you know it is here you can just Ctrl+F and find a characteristic piece of syntax:

### [syntax](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)

- [`list[[1]][[2]] = 3`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148387/5478) error
- [`foo @@ list`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21174/5478)
- [`foo @@@ list`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1970/5478) (*could be better*)
- [`list[[;; ;; n]];` or `Span`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64003/5478)

### [functional-style](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-style)

- [`list[[##]]& @@ {1,2}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50675/5478)
- [`{##, foo[##]} & @@@ list`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2688/5478)

### [function-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function-construction) [variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variables)

- [`foo[x___]:=`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6588/5478)
- [`ToExpression["x"] = 5`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

### [replacement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/replacement) [pattern-matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pattern-matching) [comparison](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison)

- [`expr /. a/b -> c`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/5478)
- [Use `:>` not `->`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22917/5478)
- [Use `===` not `==`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8796/5478)
- [Use `Alternatives |` not `Or ||`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132037/5478)
- [`{(_foo|_bar)..}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84757/5478)
- [`Cases` levelspec is {1} not {0}](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23454/5478)

### [dynamic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic) [manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manipulate) [gui-construction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-construction)

- [`foo[x_]:=x a ; Manipulate[foo[x], {a,}]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10604/5478)
- [`Dynamic[4] / 2`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5817/5478)
- [`Dynamic[update; ..., TrackedSymbols:>{update}]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2857/5478)
- [Don't forget `TrackedSymbols:>{}` when `UpdateInterval` is set.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9766/5478)
- [`Method->"Queued"` for `Button`+ `MessageDialog`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44825/5478)

### [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation)

- [`{{5, 4}, {5, 2}, {5, 1}} - {2, 2}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31894/5478)
- [`{foo, bar} + {{a,b},{c,d}}` ---> `{{foo[a], bar[b]}, {foo[c], bar[d]}}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11298/5478)
- [`foo + {1,2,3,4}` ---> `{1, f[2, 3], 4}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28522/5478)
- [`{#[[1, 1]], #[[;; , 2]]}& /@ GatherBy[list, First]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26574/5478)
- [`MatrixForm[array] // Dimensions`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131982/5478)

### [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting)

- [`ContourPlot3D` quality, `MaxRecursion` or `Plot3D`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44825/5478)
- [`ListPlot @ Transpose @ {xx, yy}`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21884/5478)
- [`Show` only takes options from the first arg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44541/5478)

### [other-tags](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-tags)

- [`With[{i=i},...`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/5478)
- [`Import /@ FileNames["*.jpg"]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5242/5478)
- [`Table @ Export @ ToString @ i` with `StringJoin/StringTemplate`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17826/5478)
- [Just `ClearAll` before solving](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40314/5478)
- [`"s" <> Style["s", Red]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/5478)

tbc...

Answer (score 11):

1. Aim for the answer.

   There is no point in looking for a question duplicate as opposed to looking for an answer that fits and was posted before. If I don't know if it exists or I don't remember keywords that would help me to locate it do e.g.:

   > is:a [list-manipulation] [filtering] *+keywords specific to the most obvious answer to that question*

   Assuming the question was related to selecting form list.

   Additionally you can play with `isaccepted:yes` and `[faq]` if you are confident about the answer being the accepted one or that this is really a FAQ question.

2. I often do but don't forget about

   **[What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/5478)**

   many FAQs are answered there.

tbc..

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes the answer is built-in, it must have been asked/answered before. But good luck with finding the answer "`Transpose`" among many answers that use it.

### 'There is a function exactly for that'

I keep that list in my browser bookmarks but I decided to move it here:

#### [list-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list-manipulation)

- [`MapThread`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71988/5478)
- [`NestList`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7251/5478)
- [`SortBy`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9840/5478)
- `Table` NOT `For` [(a)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134610/5478) [(b)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144547/5478)
- [`Tally`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30859/5478)
- [`Transpose`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101769/5478)
- [`Reverse[_, 2]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105598/5478)

#### [plotting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting)

- [`ContourPlot` for implicit equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34668/5478)
- [`Show` 2D case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26446/5478)
- [`Show` 3D case](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76496/5478)

#### [other-tags](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-tags)

- [`Chop`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21674/5478)
- [`Save DumpSave Put`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1959/5478)

### Or *there is an option for that*:

- [`AspectRatio -> Automatic`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143376/5478)
- [`Axes -> False`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32189/5478)
- [`SaveDefinitions -> True`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16205/5478)

tbc...