# How do people remember relevant posts?

Tags: discussion

I just posted an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237451/12558) to a question . I know I answered a similar question previously but could not find it. xzczd however, was able to find the previous question. So either some of you have magnificent memories, clearly I do not, or else there is a way of archiving previous posts in a retrievable manner?
What tricks for dealing with previous posts do people use?

Thanks

Comment: Just in case: have you read the https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching ? I've found the post by searching [user:1871 highpassfilter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1871+highpassfilter). (1871 is the user ID of mine, yours is 12558, which can be found in your user page: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12558/hugh )

Comment: I really like how @ChrisK [used the tag wiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/interpolation/info) for storing a [list of useful posts related to interpolation functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/interpolation/info). If it became a thing to put posts one considers general/reusable in the corresponding tag wiki that would be of great value to the community. It's not the answer to your question because it's not how people currently do it, but it seems worth a mention.

Comment: @C.E. I think that's worth a separate meta question. We do need to discuss the feasibility of using a tag wiki for bookmarking canonical or "best of the best" questions.

Comment: At least closely related: [Finding duplicates](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2403/5478). @xzczd when you visit user's user page then the user:xxxx is automatically added to the search box

Comment: I'm an old geezer and have trouble remembering things like my 'phone number and my car's license plate code. So I  can seldom remember relevant previous posts. Any time I suspect a question might be a duplicate, I have to search this site and google with what I think might be the relevant descriptors, hoping to confirm my surmise.

Comment: @m_goldberg I do this too but it is often difficult. This is where duplicates help because the question and answer may have been formulated using language that I would never think of. However, is bloating StackExchange with duplicates the correct approach for helping people find answers?

Comment: Of course, it is **not** advisable to *deliberately* post dupes. But, it is not the end of the world if, despite your due diligence in searching before asking, there was a dupe you missed because you did not hit the right keywords.